# Question on $\cos(x)\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If we have $-1\le\cos(x)\le1$ and $\cos(ix)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$, then both are defined as real for real $x$.

This leads me to the conclusion that $\cos(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ if $x$ is real or imaginary.

However, I have to imagine that $\cos(x)\in\mathbb{C}$ is possible, but how?

Comment: Do you know what is $e^{i \pi/2}$

Comment: Cos x is real.  Cos ix is real.  But cos y + ix = cosy cos ix + sin y sin ix .  Sin ix *is* imaginary so cox y + ix is complex.  It *can* be purely imaginary if y=k pi + pi/2 and x isn't 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-1\le\cos(x)\le1$ is only true when x is a real number.

\begin{align}
  \cos(x + \imath y)
  &= \cos(x) \cos(\imath y) - \sin(x) \sin(\imath y)\\
  &= \dfrac 12 \cos(x) (e^y + e^{-y})
    +\dfrac 12 \imath \sin(x) (e^y - e^{-y})
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$x$ doesn't have to be real or imaginary, for example $\cos(1+i)$ is not real or imaginary.